# Belongs_To / Has Many Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

Clients have many Reports and Reports belong to a client.

However on the creation of the Report it is not assigning the client_id into the database, but not sure why?

Am i doing something wrong here?

Client Model

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Report Model

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :report
  belongs_to :client

end
```

Client Controller (Update)

```
  # PUT /clients/1
  # PUT /clients/1.json
  def update
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
        format.html { redirect_to [:admin,@client], :notice => 'Client was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @client.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Report Controller (Create)

```
  # POST /reports
  # POST /reports.json
  def create
    @report = Report.new(params[:report])
    @report.client_id = params[:client][:client_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @report.save
        format.html { redirect_to '/admin/clients', :notice => 'Report was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @report, :status => :created, :location => @report }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @report.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Client Edit View

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @client.reports.build]) do |f| %>
   <label class="formlabel">Report Upload</label>
   <%= f.file_field :report, :class=>"text-input small-input"  %> 
  <div class="actions">
    <br />
   <%= f.submit 'Upload', :class => 'button' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you verify that a value is being set for `params[:client][:client_id]`? If it isn't then you're kind of undoing the work of your `@client.reports.build` by setting it to nil. AFAIK when initializing child objects using the `.build` method it should automatically set the foreign_key for you when you run a `.save`.

Comment: Can you show us the params for your create/update actions?

Comment: Dont know if i understand what you are meaning the update action is above

Comment: Give [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) a quick read, every time you make a request to the server to do something(e.g., POST, GET) the params hash variable is sent to your respective controller action with information. In your case it's sending the data collected in your form to build a new report object. You can find out exactly what's being sent by looking at your server logs in the console. What we're interested in is if there's a value being set for `client_id` from the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious; because you're using `.build` in the form_for, the client may already be in the url.

What if you remove:

```
@report.client_id = params[:client][:client_id]
```

and submit, what happens then? Because this line is looking incorrectly at the params, so I wonder if you are overwriting that you built in the `form_for`

Either that, or a hidden field like @Adam said would work.

Comment: Hi Steph

If i remove it The Report record is created in the database but the client_id field is blank (Therefore not creating the link to the client)

Thanks

Comment: When you run `rake routes`, what is the route path for this? is it `/clients/:client_id/reports/new` ?   Please let me know what the route is when you rake, as well as what controller it says it's going to, etc.

Comment: Hi the Route is the /clients/:clients_id/edit and i was trying to do this in the edit action of the clients controller. I have however removed the column from the database and form_for and now looking a any approach that will work. What would you suggest

Answer (score 1):

The client_id doesn't have a related input field in the form on your view. You could add something to your form like:

```
f.hidden_field :client_id
```

And then in your controller, set it as:

```
@report.client_id = params[:report][:client_id]
```

Alternatively, you could include the client_id in the url.

Comment: Hi Adam

The client ID is in the URL as it is in the edit function of the Client model.  /clients/:id/edit

Comment: OK, so it's something like /clients/:client_id/reports/new ? If so, then you can just do @report.client_id = params[:client_id]. That isn't necessarily the most secure thing in the world (unless you have some controls in place, they could send through any client id they want), but it should work.

Comment: Sorry the URL is only clients/1/edit and in this view is a upload form for the report, no need for the extra URL. Tried now but unsuccessful i dont get any errors but the client_id in the report table remains empty

Comment: Does `f.hidden_field :client_id, :value => params[:id]`
do anything for you?

Comment: the hidden field is giving the same no errors the record is created in the database but the client_id is empty

Answer (score 0):

Stupid Mistake it seems needed to up the end function on the form-for for the client to close it off before opening the form-for the reports.

Then add the field for the client_id and now just hide the field as per Adam suggestion.

Thanks Steph for suggestions as this help me solve this mistake.

Thanks Everyone!  :-)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out Clay!